# How to build infinality-ultimate?

Tags: 16.04, fonts

I really want to use infinality-ultimate from bohoomil, since it's much superior to ubuntu font rendering in my eyes, and it seems ubuntu/canonical are not really fixing their bugs in theirs anymore (like in google chrome, arial have different height from 100% to 110% (110% works alright, but 100% is too small, quite weird..) but bohoomil's patches does not have these issues. He also does things like added new patches from google (emoji support) in cairo etc.

I have looked at http://bohoomil.com/doc/02-building/ but these does not seem complete.. Maybe someone here can help?

I'm normally guide good at figure stuff like that out, but I really can't figure out how to patch this, or build.

Will start a bounty ASAP for 200 reputation, if that makes you want to write a better guide / how to and get some sweet reputation ;-)

I'm using xenial (16.04) if that matters.

Comment: Would you mind mentioning some bugs which "ubuntu/canonical are not really fixing"?

Comment: this is really a question for the maintainer of `infinality` and not germane to Ubuntu itself.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Ubuntu font rendering have some "problems" with Arial for instance, It looks just fine with free fonts, but with Arial it makes it look VERY different than on Windows, it looks like a whole other font.. Different height etc. Other fonts are just fine, the biggest problem I have found is arial, but too many websites use it to ignore it. I'm a little OCD ;) it might sound stupid.

Comment: Also, for a long time Google have "patched" fontconfig to support google's emojis (their standard at least) see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1543921 , but no one cares to implement it. I'm not saying they SHOULD do it, but I'm choosing to use another solution I find better.

Comment: Thanks. The bug you mention was filed two months before the release of 16.04 (without specifying a package). fontconfig was upgraded after that. Added a question to the bug report. As regards Arial in Google Chrome, wouldn't that rather be a Chrome issue?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Also, the Arial problem is present in firefox as well, I now also see verdana looks very different to other font rendering. (it's more square?, too bold I think) I can post some screenshots to you somewhere, if you want @GunnarHjalmarsson ?

Comment: Please note that both Arial and Verdana are proprietary fonts, and good replacement sans-serif fonts are shipped with Ubuntu by default. So if I understand it correctly, the rendering issues you mention are related to manually installed fonts from external locations. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't know if I would call them external locations, since they come from ttf-mscorefonts-installer. I think a Lot of people download them and expect them to look like they should. That being said, I understand if Ubuntu don't want to use time on it. That's just why I prefer Infinality. :-)

Comment: Ok, then we understand each other. Hopefully someone helps you with the actual question, but as @AndrewKeech mentioned, the chances are probably better if you ask those whose maintain the thing.

Comment: Have you looked at this PPA https://launchpad.net/~rjvbertin/+archive/ubuntu/infinaltimate ? - it applies the [bohoomil](https://github.com/bohoomil/fontconfig-ultimate "bohoomil") config regardless of the version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but maybe this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial) can help ? 
Looks like it uses [bohoomil fontconfig-ultimate](https://github.com/achaphiv/ppa-fonts/blob/master/ppa/README.md#distribution--1404)

Comment: The PPA does not use quite the same patches as bohoomil does on arch himself. It looks quite different. But I managed to find a PPA from trusty and build it myself against newer infinality. But thanks anyway :-)